# how any decision would unfold

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It remains unclear **how any decision about the Olympics would unfold** if officials in Tokyo conclude they have to alter plans for the Games.

What does the sentence mean?
How the decision will be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the verb **unfold** implies the process of reaching the decision as well as the result itself.

It also points to the implications of altering the plans as these have involved vast costs and construction programmes, to say nothing of multiple hotel bookings.

To unfold suggests opening something that is hidden or going from one state (often illustrated by an insect with folded wings) to another (wings extended). So the word is more illustrative than just **made**.